# ConnectN game check horizontal win

Tags: python

Im trying to code for a Connect4 Game but instead of having 4 game pieces in a row, I will have 5 pieces. So I'm trying to check for a horizontal win but as I tested my code, nothing prints out and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong?

```
game_board = [['_','_','_','_','_','_','_'],
         ['_','_','_','_','_','_','_'],
         ['_','_','_','X','_','_','_'],
         ['_','_','_','O','_','_','_'],
         ['_','X','O','O','O','O','O'],
         ['X','X','X','O','O','X','O']]

num_col= 7
num_row= 6
num_piece= 5
game_piece= 'O'

for r in range(num_row):
  for c in range(num_col-num_piece):
    index=0
    for i in range (num_piece):
      if game_board[r][c + index] == game_piece:
        index +=1
      else:
        break
      if index == num_piece:
        print('end game')
```

Answer (score 0):

In this loop:

```
for c in range(num_col-num_piece):
```

you're only going to be looking at columns 0 and 1 (i.e. the two before the row of `'O'` starts), since the end of a `range` is non-inclusive.  If you add 1 to that range then I think this scheme might work.

When you want to try to tackle vertical and diagonal rows I recommend giving this a read: [Finding neighbor cells in a grid with the same value. Ideas how to improve this function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394088/finding-neighbor-cells-in-a-grid-with-the-same-value-ideas-how-to-improve-this/61395017#61395017)