# ConnectN Checking for Diagonal Wins

Tags: python, list

So Im currently writing codes to check for a diagonal win in a game of connect3, but for some reason, no print statement shows up, can someone check whats wrong

```
board = [['_','X','X','O'],
         ['_','X','X','O'],
         ['X','X','O','O']]
num_row = 3
num_col = 4
num_piece = 3 #game pieces needed to win 
game_piece = 'X'
```

```
# check / diagonal win
for rows in range(num_row - num_piece + 1):
    for cols in range(num_piece, num_col):
        index = 0
        for counts in range(num_piece):
            if board[rows + index][cols - index] == game_piece:
                index += 1
            else:
                break
            if index == num_piece:
                print('game end')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code only tests the first diagonal (starting from the upper right):

```
>>> for rows in range(num_row - num_piece + 1):
...     for cols in range(num_piece, num_col):
...         index = 0
...         print(f"testing {rows, cols}")
...         for counts in range(num_piece):
...             if board[rows + index][cols - index] == game_piece:
...                 index += 1
...             else:
...                 break
...             if index == num_piece:
...                 print('game end')
...
testing (0, 3)
```

Since you want to test every diagonal starting at column 2 (the 3rd column), you want to subtract 1 from the start of that range:

```
>>> for rows in range(num_row - num_piece + 1):
...     for cols in range(num_piece - 1, num_col):
...         index = 0
...         print(f"testing {rows, cols}")
...         for counts in range(num_piece):
...             if board[rows + index][cols - index] == game_piece:
...                 index += 1
...             else:
...                 break
...             if index == num_piece:
...                 print('game end')
...
testing (0, 2)
game end
testing (0, 3)
```

See also: [Finding neighbor cells in a grid with the same value. Ideas how to improve this function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394088/finding-neighbor-cells-in-a-grid-with-the-same-value-ideas-how-to-improve-this/61395017#61395017)