# python code that will compare a list of numbers to a list of sets of numbers

Tags: python

I am doing a simple tic tac toe game in python. The point at which I have gotten stuck is validating whether or not someone has won. I am trying to make it as short and simple as possible, as well as easily adaptable so I can use the technique for some other project ideas. I am working on the whole program in chunks and only need help with this part right now. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

I am aware I could make a bunch of if else statements of even some version of select case, but I am trying to see if there is a simple way in python where I can adapt the code to do the same thing with dynamic datasets.

I start with creating a token system which I have tied to positions on my tic tac toe board. When a player selects a position of 1-9 to occupy, the corresponding token is passed to the player_tokens list and removes the item from the tokens list. This helps to prevent the overwriting of a cell and also track positions for each player cell

```
tokens = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
player_tokens = []
keys = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]]
```

On each turn I am wanting a function to compare the list tokens, and see if it contains a matching set in keys. if it does it would return a win.

```
tokens = [3,5,6,7,8]
player_tokens = [1,2,4,9]
keys = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]]
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394088/finding-neighbor-cells-in-a-grid-with-the-same-value-ideas-how-to-improve-this/61395017#61395017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Python standard library `itertools` which is great for these things.  The `combinations` function can be used here:

```
threes = list(itertools.combinations(player_tokens,3))
```

`threes` becomes a list of all unique 3-element tuples in `player_tokens`, which can be used to check against the "winning" keys:

```
#note that I changed your example slightly to include a 3-in-a-row
tokens = [3,5,6,7,8]
player_tokens = [1,2,3,9]
keys = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]]

threes = list(itertools.combinations(player_tokens,3))

print(threes)
print([sorted(x) in keys for x in threes])  #using sorted to convert tuple to list and make sure is in order
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 9), (1, 3, 9), (2, 3, 9)]
[True, False, False, False]
```

You could use `any` to see if any of the boolean list is `True` (aka if the move created a 3-position combination that was a win).

Comment: This method worked great for my project. Thank you for your assistance. While I am experienced in other languages such as C, C++, C#, Java, etc., I am fairly new to python so I am still learning all of the methods and functions python has to offer.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I'd suggest to use actual python sets!

```py
rows = [{1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9},
        {1, 4, 7},
        {2, 5, 8},
        {3, 6, 9},
        {1, 5, 9},
        {3, 5, 7}]

def is_three_in_a_row(player_tokens):
    return any(row.issubset(player_tokens) for row in rows)
```

Where `.issubset` will perform the check we care about:

```py
is_three_in_a_row({1, 2, 3, 4})  # True

is_three_in_a_row({2, 3, 4, 5})  # False
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. While I didn't use it for the project I was working on, I can definitely see the ease of use of this method in some other project ideas that I have. Thank you for sharing your knowledge

Answer (score 0):

you should change `player_tokens` to a set. Initialize it as  `set()` and use add instead of append. 
To check use `player_tokens.contains(keys[i])`.

Try `help(set.contains)` in console.

To check all u can use `any(player_tokens.contains(keys[i])  for i in len keys)`

Comment: Thank you for the info. I am sure this method will come in handy later on when I start making bigger lists and sets