# Noughts and Crosses Game

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I created an input, for example, this one:

```
O,0,0;O,1,0;X,2,0;X,0,1;O,1,1;,2,1;,0,2;O,1,2;X,2,2
```

The first character is the "nought" and the other two (separated by ",") are the position in the matrix. This specific noughts and crosses game would look like this:

```
game = [["O", 0, 0], ["O", 1, 0], ["X", 2, 0], ["X", 0, 1], ["O", 1, 1], ["", 2, 1], ["O", 0, 2], ["O", 1, 2], ["X", 2, 2]]

or if you want to look at it this way:
 O O X
 X O - 
 O O X
```

Here, player: "O" is the winner

The output I want to achieve is to say who the winner is ("X" or "O") or if there is a draw or if the game hasn't ended yet.

Another example of a game could be this one:

```
O,0,0;O,1,0;X,2,0;,0,1;,1,1;X,2,1;X,0,2;O,1,2;,2,2
```

The game would look like this:

```
game = [["O", 0, 0], ["", 1, 0], ["X", 2, 0], ["", 0, 1], ["", 1, 1], ["X", 2, 1], ["X", 0, 2], ["O", 1, 2], ["", 2, 2]]

Or:
 O - X
 - - X 
 X O -
```

Here the game hasn't ended yet

Another example could be:

```
O,0,0;O,1,0;X,2,0;X,0,1;X,1,1;O,2,1;O,0,2;X,1,2;O,2,2

The game would look like:
game = [["O", 0, 0], [O", 1, 0], ["X", 2, 0], ["X", 0, 1], ["X", 1, 1], ["O", 2, 1], ["O", 0, 2], ["X", 1, 2], ["O", 2, 2]]

Or:
 O O X
 X X O 
 O X O
```

As you can see there is a draw.

This is what I've tried:

```
string = input("Insert a game")
g = string.split(";")
for i in range(len(g)):
    g[i] = g[i].split()
for i in range(len(g)):
    g[i] = g[i].split(",")
g2 = g.copy()
del(g2[0][1])
del(g2[0][2])
```

I wanted to make another list only for the crosses and noughts, so it would be easier for me to say when "X" or "O" won, but it isn't working, it doesn't delete the other two following numbers that are next to it.
I don't know if it's a good idea though, maybe there is an easier way of doing the whole problem. I don't really know how to write a code to check the conditions (who won, if it's a draw or if it hasn't finished).

If you don't know the game, I will write the instructions:

Someone wins if:

-There are three spaces occupied horizontally by the same player

-There are three spaces occupied vertically by the same player

-There are three spaces occupied making a diagonal by the same player

There is a draw if:

-Each of the spaces are occupied and it isn't a case mentioned before.

The game hasn't ended if:

-We aren't in any of the conditions mentioned before and there are "blank" spaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding neighbor cells in a grid with the same value. Ideas how to improve this function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394088/finding-neighbor-cells-in-a-grid-with-the-same-value-ideas-how-to-improve-this)

Comment: Shouldn't the second loop use `g[i].split(',')`?

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about tic-tac-toe, click on the tag.

Comment: And why do you repeat that second loop?

Comment: I don't get your objective, what's the problem you getting there?

Comment: Stack Overflow tries to focus on narrow questions about specific problems. "Here's what I'm trying to accomplish and here's my current code", without focusing on a specific problem (and removing all the parts that aren't essential to that problem), is generally considered too broad to be on-topic.

Comment: my problem is I don't know how to check the conditions of the game in code, I'm just starting in Python and I think I need help

Answer (score 0):

```
string = input("Insert a game")
g = string.split(";")
for i in range(len(g)):
    g[i] = g[i].split()
for i in range(len(g)):
    g[i] = g[i].split(",")
g2 = g.copy()
del(g2[0][1])
del(g2[0][2])
```

One of your loops is unnecessary, the only loop you need is:

```
for i, lst in enumerate(g):
    g[i] = lst.split(",")
```

and with List Comprehension you can make it even better:

```
new_g = [lst.split(",") for lst in g]
```

and if you don't need the positions any more and you want to del them then you can do:

```
new_g2 = [lst[0] for lst in new_g]
```

so the final code should be:

```
string = input("Insert a game")
g = string.split(";")
new_g = [lst.split(",") for lst in g]
new_g2 = [lst[0] for lst in new_g]
```