# How can I check the adjacent dictonary keys in a tictactoe game?

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I've been reading *Automate The Boring Stuff* and I've created this tictactoe game. I'm wondering whether it's possible to check for a three in a row using dictionaries. I understand that I could compare the board states each time to set values but that seems really inefficient to me. This is my code:

```
theBoard = {"top-L": "", "top-M":"", "top-R":"",
            "mid-L": "", "mid-M": "", "mid-R": "",
            "low-L": "", "low-M": "", "low-R": ""}

def printBoard(board):
    print(board["top-L"] + "|" + board["top-M"] + "|" + board["top-R"])
    print("-+-+-")
    print(board["mid-L"] + "|" + board["mid-M"] + "|" + board["mid-R"])
    print("-+-+-")
    print(board["low-L"] + "|" + board["low-M"] + "|" + board["low-R"])

turn = "X"
for i in range(9):
    printBoard(theBoard)
    print("Turn for " + turn + "player. Move on which space?")
    move = input()
    theBoard[move] = turn
    if turn == "X":
        turn = "O"
    else:
        turn = "X"

printBoard(theBoard)
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61395017/3799759  Using Cartesian coordinates to express your board rather than a dictionary makes things a lot simpler IMO.

Comment: Since you're using a dictionary, you could create a list-of-lists-of-all-combinations-of-keys that form a three-in-row combination, and then just check what's in each of them after each move that involve one of the keys.

Comment: It *is* really inefficient: you chose a board representation that does not model the physical relationships you want for the game.  I strongly suggest that you research the common approaches to 2D board games and change your design.  Stack Overflow is not a design review resource.

Answer (score 0):

obviously that dict is not the appropriate data type in this case, but a bit of hard work, without any tricks, and it's work. you can take this:

```
def check_three_in_row(board):
    all_lines = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
    for key, value in board.items():
        if key.startswith("top"):
            all_lines[0].append(value)
        if key.startswith("mid"):
            all_lines[1].append(value)
        if key.startswith("low"):
            all_lines[2].append(value)
        if key.endswith("R"):
            all_lines[3].append(value)
        if key.endswith("M"):
            all_lines[4].append(value)
        if key.endswith("L"):
            all_lines[5].append(value)
        if key == "top-L" or key == "mid-M" or key == "low-R":
            all_lines[6].append(value)
        if key == "top-R" or key == "mid-M" or key == "low-L":
            all_lines[7].append(value)
    for line in all_lines:
        if len(set(line)) == 1 and len(line) == 3 and line[0] != '':
            return line[0]
    return None
    

theBoard = {"top-L": "", "top-M":"", "top-R":"",
"mid-L": "", "mid-M": "", "mid-R": "",
"low-L": "", "low-M": "", "low-R": ""}
def printBoard(board):
    print(board["top-L"] + "|" + board["top-M"] + "|" + board["top-R"])
    print("-+-+-")
    print(board["mid-L"] + "|" + board["mid-M"] + "|" + board["mid-R"])
    print("-+-+-")
    print(board["low-L"] + "|" + board["low-M"] + "|" + board["low-R"])
turn = "X"
for i in range(9):
    printBoard(theBoard)
    winner = check_three_in_row(theBoard)
    if winner != '' and winner is not None:
        print(f'The winner is {winner}')
    print("Turn for " + turn + "player. Move on which space?")
    move = input()
    theBoard[move] = turn
    if turn == "X":
        turn = "O"
    else:
        turn = "X"

printBoard(theBoard)
```

last part of the output:

```
Turn for Xplayer. Move on which space?

low-M
|X|O
-+-+-
|X|O
-+-+-
|X|
The winner is X
```