# In Python, connect 4 game, check for win function does not work

Tags: python

I am writing a connect 4 game in python but checkforwin function isn't working, it is like it does not exists for some reason,when it is called and it is supposed to return True it does nothing, here is my code (I have added some comments to the function that isn't working):

```
# "\u25A1" == small square
mainList = [["\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1"],
         ["\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1"],
         ["\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1"],
         ["\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1"],
         ["\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1"],
         ["\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1","\u25A1"]]

def drawBoardFunc():
    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(7):
            print(mainList[i][j],end='')
        print("")

def checkForWinX():  #Here is the problem this function does nothing
    #Horizontal win for "X"
    for i in range(5,-1,-1):
        for j in range(4):
            if (mainList[i][j]=="X" and mainList[i][j+1]=="X"
            and mainList[i][j+2]=="X" and mainList[i][j+3]=="X"):
                return True

def checkForWinO():  #Here again the same problem
    #Horizontal win for "O"
    for i in range(5,-1,-1):
        for j in range(4):
            if (mainList[i][j]=="O" and mainList[i][j+1]=="O" and
                mainList[i][j+2]=="O" and mainList[i][j+3]=="O"):
                return True
        

drawBoardFunc()
#This list stores the row that its about to put a mark
checkRowList = [5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
player = 1
while True:
    print("Player's",player,"turn")
    chosenColumn = int(input("Please choose a column from 0 to 6 to play:\n"))
    if checkRowList[chosenColumn] == -1:
        print("Column full, please choose another column")
    else:
        if player == 1:
            row = checkRowList[chosenColumn]
            mainList[row][chosenColumn] = "Χ"
            checkRowList[chosenColumn] -= 1
            player = 2
            drawBoardFunc()
            win = checkForWinX()  #Here it is called for "X"
            if win==True:
                print("Player one win!")
                break
        elif player == 2:
            row = checkRowList[chosenColumn]
            mainList[row][chosenColumn] = "Ο"
            checkRowList[chosenColumn] -= 1
            player = 1
            drawBoardFunc()
            if checkForWinO()==True:  #Here it is called for "O" (in a little different way)
                print("Player two win!")
                break
```

I have two same checkforwin functions that make the same work, one for player "X" and one for player "O" so I refer as it is only one, I hope that it is clear, if you want more details let me know and please help.
edit: I forgot to say that this program is a work in progress and I only check for horizontal win condition.

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: your function only checks for one direction of a win, you need to check for vertical, horizontal, and diagonal wins

Comment: It's easy to get bogged down implementing each individual direction.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/61395017/3799759 for an approach that involves less copying and pasting.

Comment: It may be something simple, all seems to be ok, I don't understand why the function checkforwin does not return True when the conditions met

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very unfortunate error, but it appears to be the following.

In your while loop, you have the following line

```
mainList[row][chosenColumn] = "Χ"
```

And in your function to check if the X player has won, you check if the cell is equal to X, like so.

```
mainList[i][j]=="X"
```

Now, the reason that the function does not return `true` is because the `X` you assign in the while loop is **not** the same `X` that you check against in the  `checkForWinX` function. Somehow you accidently copied/used a unusual X from somewhere else.

```
>>> "X" == "Χ"
False

>>> "X".encode('utf-8') # this is the one you use in checkForWinX
b'X'
>>> "Χ".encode('utf-8') # this is the one you assign to mainList[row][chosenColumn]
b'\xce\xa7'
```

Depending on your browser, you can use ctrl+f (find) to look for X and you'll see that not each X lights up.

Comment: Yes problem solved, unbeliavable it was the "X" in Greek language!! Thank you very much!